# why i can not find the folder i have created using path _provider, i searched for it in the file manager app(android 12) but i did not find it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-external-storage

This is the code to the function which i used for creataing a folder.

note: i have tested if the folder exist using the .exist function and its already exist, but i can not find it in the file manager app.

```
Future<String> getFilePath() async {
  Directory endPointDirectory=Directory("");
  const String folderName="cameraFlutter";// there folder where we will save files to it
  var directory=getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .then((value) async {
    final Directory endPointDirectory=Directory("${value!.path}/$folderName");
    if (await endPointDirectory.exists()) {
      print("exist");
      print(endPointDirectory.path);

    } else {
    //if folder not exists create folder and then return its path
      print("not exist");
      await endPointDirectory.create();

    }

  }).catchError((onError){
    print(onError.toString());

  });
  return endPointDirectory.path;//external storage directory
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY5mL.png)

Answer (score 0):

just print to see the path

```
...
....

final Directory endPointDirectory = Directory("${value!.path}/$folderName");

print(endPointDirectory);

....
...
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: why do you think that ?

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cameraapp/files/cameraFlutter

Comment: yes so in android studio you would open file explorer and navigate to that folder   https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer